# How to one-time authentification for two differents servers?

Tags: php, html, submit

I have two servers (i.e) server1 and server2 with different login-pages.

**server1**
login_server1.php

```
<form method="post" action="$ACTION$">
    <input name="auth_user" type="email">
    <input name="auth_pass" type="password">
    <input name="redirurl" type="hidden" value="$REDIRURL$">
    <input name="accept" type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

So on login error, server1 returns

login_server1_error.php

```
<form method="post" action="$ACTION$">
    <p class="login-error">$MESSAGE$</p>
    <input name="auth_user" type="email">
    <input name="auth_pass" type="password">
    <input name="redirurl" type="hidden" value="$REDIRURL$">
    <input name="accept" type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

**Server2** offers an automatic authetification to login and goto an url on this server. this is the process

```
<?php
/*
AutoAuth Script
*/

# Define Server2 URL & AutoAuth Key
$server2url = "http://server2/dologin.php";
$autoauthkey = "abcXYZ123";

$timestamp = time(); # Get current timestamp
$email = "user@mail.com"; # Clients Email Address to Login
$goto = "clientarea.php?action=products";

$hash = sha1($email.$timestamp.$autoauthkey); # Generate Hash

# Generate AutoAuth URL & Redirect
$url = $server2url."?email=$email&timestamp=$timestamp&hash=$hash&goto=".urlencode($goto);
header("Location: $url");
exit;

?>
```

Sow how to access server2url when sever1 form submit action ?

Answer (score 0):

I have solve the problem with $_POST...

In **Server1** first login page, i've wrote:

```
<form method="post" action="$ACTION$">
    <input name="auth_user" type="email">
    <input name="auth_pass" type="password">
    <input name="redirurl" type="hidden" value="$REDIRURL$">
    <input name="accept" type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

And in its second login_error page this:

```
...
</head>
<?php
    $user_email = $_POST['auth_user']; # For retrieve user email entered before this page
    $user_pwd   = $_POST['auth_pass']; # For retrieve user password entered before this page
?>
<script>
    if $MESSAGE$=="Insufficient" {

        <?php
            /*
            Auto Authentification code
            */
            # Define URL & AutoAuth Key
            $server2url = "http://server2/dologin.php";
            $autoauthkey = "abcXYZ123";

            $timestamp = time()-10; # Get current timestamp
            $email = "$user_email"; # Clients Email Address to Login
            $goto = "clientarea.php?action=products";

            $hash = sha1($email.$timestamp.$autoauthkey); # Generate Hash

            # Generate AutoAuth URL & Redirect
            $url = $server2url."?email=$email&timestamp=$timestamp&hash=$hash&goto=".urlencode($goto);
            header("Location: $url");
            exit;
        ?>
    }
</script>

<body>
<form method="post" action="$ACTION$">
    <p class="login-error">$MESSAGE$</p>
    <input name="auth_user" type="email">
    <input name="auth_pass" type="password">
    <input name="redirurl" type="hidden" value="$REDIRURL$">
    <input name="accept" type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
</body>
```

The code works fine now (e.i) when users click on submit button on first login.html page with good login informations (but insufficient "credits" to access the SI), datas are send to **Server1**. It see that the client credit is "insufficient" to access the SI. So, it (**Server1**) respond with login_error.html page which execute first a script to retrieve _POST[data] informations and then redirect user's infos to **Server2**'s auto-login page.

This sounds really pretty as it was too simple to be difficult loOol.

Enjoy !